# Install apps from the store without an account

Tags: windows-11, windows-11-upgrade

In windows 10 it is possible to install all the free apps from the microsoft store without logging in with the microsoft account (just close the window and the download starts automatically).  In windows 11 have they removed this possibility?  Is there a workaround?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no workaround for Windows 11. There is no harm or safety issue in using a Microsoft Account.

So best approach is to change your local Account to a Microsoft Account (nothing will be lost) and then you can use the Store.

Two Windows 11 machines here: 1 Production and 1 Insider. The Insider machine has both Local and Microsoft Accounts.